# #ASK Can data API stored on memory device user?

Tags: javascript, caching, cookies

so i've dinamic menu that come from database, when i stored in cookies, cookies have a size limit and if i'm used call api, and if i call API continuously the server load is very large
any solution?

this examp of my data json in cookies browser, oh yeah i'm used stack FrontEnd vanila javascript and backend NodeJs

```
[{%22ids%22:%221%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}%2C{%22ids%22:%222%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}%2C{%22ids%22:%223%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}%2C{%22ids%22:%224%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}%2C{%22ids%22:%225%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}%2C{%22ids%22:%227%22%2C%22can_view%22:1%2C%22can_create%22:1%2C%22can_update%22:1%2C%22can_delete%22:1%2C%22can_show_terminal%22:1%2C%22can_show_ip_on_table%22:1%2C%22can_open_kubernates_terminal%22:1}]
```

can store large data on browser without call API continuously

Comment: You could persist the data locally in the client using localStorage.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: unfotunately localstorage has a maximum size ref: [here](https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html)